# How to create a deb package for a python project without setup.py

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py, deb, python-poetry

Any documentation I've found about this topic mentions that the "only" requirement to build a deb package is to have a correct `setup.py` (and `requirements.txt`). For instance in [dh-virtualenv tutorial](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/tutorial.html#step-2-set-up-packaging-for-your-project), [stdeb documentation](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/) and [the Debian's library style guide for python](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide).

But nowadays new (amazing) tools like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) allow to develop (and upload to PyPI) python projects without any `setup.py` (this file and several others including `requirements.txt` are all replaced by `pyproject.toml`). I believe [flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) allows this too.

I have developed a python project managed by poetry and would like to package it for Ubuntu/Debian. I guess, as a workaround I can still write a `setup.py` file that would take its values from `pyproject.toml` and a `requirements.txt` file (written by hand using values from `poetry.lock`).

But, is there a way to do this without any `setup.py` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setuptools`, and the `setup.py` file that it requires, has been the de-facto packaging standard in python for the longest time. The new package managers you mention were enabled by the introduction of [`PEP 517`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) and [`PEP 518`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) (or read [this](https://snarky.ca/what-the-heck-is-pyproject-toml/) for a high-level description on the topic), which provide a standardized way of specifying the build backend without the need of a `setup.py` (and the ensuing hen-egg problem where you already need `setuptools` to correctly parse it, but might also need to specify which version of setuptools you want for the build).

Anyway, it's all still very fresh, and the linux packaging community hasn't fully caught up yet. I found [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=984824) discussion on the debian bug tracker, and the `rpm` side sums it up neatly [over here](https://discuss.python.org/t/tool-to-build-a-rpm-package-backed-by-pep-517/4020).

The short answer is to just wait a while until the toolchain catches up to the new standards, and google `debian packaging pep517 support` every now and then.

---

As a workaround for `poetry`-build packages specifically, you can use [`dephell`](https://pypi.org/project/dephell/) to generate the `setup.py`, and `poetry` to generate the `requirements.txt` for you to keep using legacy tools:

```
dephell deps convert --from=poetry --to=setuppy
poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt
```

And, during the build, tell your `pyproject.tom` that you plan to use `setuptools` for the build instead of `poetry`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 40.6.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently packaging some python software project based on poetry and there should now be some dedicated Debian packages supporting [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) build backends such as: [pybuild-plugin-pyproject](https://packages.debian.org/sid/pybuild-plugin-pyproject) or [python3-poetry-core](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-poetry-core)

You can find usage example of these in [python-jsonschema](https://sources.debian.org/src/python-jsonschema/4.10.3-2/debian/control/) debian package.