# Building Debian Python Package with Poetry

Tags: python, debian, packaging

I try to build a debian package from the python package `python-pam`.

I followed mostly this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gh-888/0c69a350a8bcfff0c12b2d1c553b6fb6).

Because the description is based on `setup.py`, but `python-pam` is based on `pyproject.toml` I tried to combine the information of this question: [How to create a deb package for a python project without setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304163/how-to-create-a-deb-package-for-a-python-project-without-setup-py)

I updated my `control` file to:

```yaml
Source: python-pam
Section: python
Priority: optional
Maintainer: username <username@mail.com>
Uploaders:
  username <username@mail.com>
Build-Depends:
  debhelper-compat (= 13),
  dh-python,
  python3-all,
  pybuild-plugin-pyproject,
  python3-poetry-core,
Standards-Version: 4.5.1
Homepage: https://pypi.org/project/python-pam/
Rules-Requires-Root: no
Vcs-Git: https://github.com/FirefighterBlu3/python-pam.git
Vcs-Browser: https://github.com/FirefighterBlu3/python-pam
X-Python3-Version: >= 3.7

Package: python3-python-pam
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Depends:
  python3-six,
  ${misc:Depends},
  ${python3:Depends}
Description: python-pam for authentication in python
  Python pam module supporting py3 (and py2) for Linux type systems (!windows)
```

and reduced the `rules` to the following minimal:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# You must remove unused comment lines for the released package.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```

If I try to run:

```bash
gbp buildpackage --git-pristine-tar
```

I've got an error about my ssh-key which I used to sign the tag previous isn't bound to my user name. I might be able to figure this out by myself, but I struggle with my simple rules file.

So far as I understand, the rules describes the steps necessary to build the package. I used poetry in the past, but only for building Pypi-Packages. At this point I am not sure how to continue the rules file or, what else I might miss. The json package mentioned in the other question seems to at lot of other stuff, which python-pam doesn't provide.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Yesterday on ubuntu22.04 I did it correctly. But failed because of the missing poetry package. I the minimal approach for `rules` correct? I am not sure how the `dpb` is able to differentiate between setup.py and poetry.

Comment: Then probably [edit] your question to remove the spurious error and focus on the problem you really wanted to ask about. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I changed the scope of the question and sadly I think the problem is based on the python-pam repository. It seems the build process of the package is a bit mixed up. I might test around with an example project I created myself. But I think the new direction of the question is legit, since the information about `gpb` with `poetry` is very limited.